# Existence of antiderivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ be given by $f(x)=sen(\frac{1}{x})$ si $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=c$ si $x=0$, where $c\in [-1,1]$ 
For which values of c there is an antiderivative?

Proof (attempt): I want to use a proposition: $f$ is continuous if, and only if, $osc(\Omega)=0$, because $f$ is discontinuous at all points $c\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what $sen$ and $osc$ mean before we can help you! Also $\Omega$.

Comment: If $f$ has an antiderivative then $f(x) = F'(x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.  The fundamental theorem of calculus implies $F(x) = F(0) + \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ and it follows that $c = f(0) = F'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \sin(1/t) \, dt$.  But it can be shown that last limit is $0$ -- so $c = 0$.